# How do i setup route53 to use two load balancers with different "part" targets

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-load-balancer

I have an example.com site that currently uses a load balancer with multiple servers.

We wish to launch an isolated application and route /path to only that new isolated load balancer.

I can create  Listener of "/path" in the load balancers; but for the life of me I cannot figure out how to best structure Route53 to allow for the use of a setup that follows this psuedocode:

`if REQUEST is "/path" or "/path/*"
    use load balancer B
else
   use load balancer A`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application Load Balancer the only thing you'll need. Within their you create 2 target groups, 1 for 1 app and 1 for another (or as I did, run them on different ports and assign each target group to its own port. Therefore I utilise 1 set of auto scaling servers fro all applications)

Going down your route though, create 2 target groups, pointing to the respective servers needed for each app and then just create the path rules under the load balancer listener tab and send each path to the correct target group.

Regards

Liam

Comment: Awesome! Listener was where it was at!
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/listener-update-rules.html?icmpid=docs_elbv2_console